# How do I replace partial xml text within a very long text string in an Oracle DB using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new to SQL and can't figure out this issue. I have tried searching Google but as you know, it returns so many results it would take for ever to find the answer, if it is even possible to do what I need.

I am using TOAD to try and update a very small portion of a very, very long xml statement in a data field within a table in an Oracle DB.

Small sample of xml text:

```
 .....<DESCRIPTION>MXINPG-*RB4-CONGESTED-AT&T SC </DESCRIPTION> <OWNERUSERNAME>Existing Text</OWNERUSERNAME>....
```

I only need to replace the <OWNERUSERNAME> **Existing Text**  </OWNERUSERNAME>
with
<OWNERUSERNAME>**New Text** </OWNERUSERNAME>

I tried a few SQL statements but none of them work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Comment: The text you've posted is not an XML fragment. Please post sample data, desired output and your current attempt with the description of the issue with it

Comment: I'm new to this site so my xml example also had some html tags to help show how the xml appears since it didn't appear correctly when I first pasted it. Looking at the history of this post, looks like someone made an edit to my tags and nothing looks like what I originally posted.  To sum it up, I'm just trying to replace a very short portion of text in a very large test string which just happens to be xml.

Comment: Hi Jose, this is what I have played around with so far. UPDATE table... SET xmlstring='New Text' where xmlstring='Existing Text' and ID=1234567

Comment: If there is only one <OWNERUSERNAME> element in the string, just use REGEXP_REPLACE